# Drag And Drop SharePoint WebParts in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: web-part, browser-compatibility

i am having a problem with drag and drop of Share-point web-parts in browsers other than I.E.

the drag and drop of Share-point web-parts in internet explorer works fine . but in any other browser it ll not work . i don't know the way to enable it in .

is there any way to make drag and drop of Share-point web-parts ,cross browser compatible.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Please refer following link for Browser support in SharePoint 2010, specifically refer for Mozile which says drag and drop web part feature is not supported.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no